# URL Repository Not Found: Provisioning Exception in Eclipse Kepler

Tags: eclipse, url, repository, eclipse-kepler, equinox

I am experiencing difficulty in the retrieval of repositories from URL sites for eclipse kepler. I have several URL's that I am attempting to fetch to no avail; they are mostly zip files, a few check sums, and a few tar bzip files. Each URL, when you navigate to it in a web browser, has intact files and none of them are broken sites. This tells me that there must be some kind of error in my eclipse build regarding its repository management. I am sharing my current build with a colleague who is not experiencing these repository issues, which is what has led me to post a question here.

I am going to keep tracing the stack, but I would greatly appreciate any cues!

```
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.ProvisionException: No repository found at http://googleappengine.googlecode.com/files/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.1.1.ziptype%2520or%2520select%2520a%2520site.
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.fail(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:395)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:692)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:96)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:92)
at org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.LoadMetadataRepositoryJob.doLoad(LoadMetadataRepositoryJob.java:117)
at org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.LoadMetadataRepositoryJob.runModal(LoadMetadataRepositoryJob.java:102)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.ui.sdk.PreloadingRepositoryHandler$2.runModal(PreloadingRepositoryHandler.java:83)
at org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations.ProvisioningJob.run(ProvisioningJob.java:177)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

And here is another example of a repository that I am trying to access:

```
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.ProvisionException: No repository found at http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/xulrunner/releases/2.0/runtimes/xulrunner-2.0.en-US.linux-i686.tar.bz2.
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.fail(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:395)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:692)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:96)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:92)
at org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.LoadMetadataRepositoryJob.doLoad(LoadMetadataRepositoryJob.java:117)
at org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.LoadMetadataRepositoryJob.runModal(LoadMetadataRepositoryJob.java:102)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.ui.sdk.PreloadingRepositoryHandler$2.runModal(PreloadingRepositoryHandler.java:83)
at org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations.ProvisioningJob.run(ProvisioningJob.java:177)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

Does someone mind telling me why this provision exception occurs? Am I missing critical plugins for eclipse? I'd be interested to know if there is a way to automate the resolution of these exceptions in finding the repositories as well...